# service red5 restart FAILED

Tags: services

Works to start and stop but not to restart:

> ```
> -bash-4.1# service red5 restart
>    Shutting down red5:                              [FAILED]
> ```

It was all working before had to delete red5 and JDK and reinstall and now this is happening. Have no clue why.

On Linux CentOS 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typical if you removed the old red5 and did not shut it down before you did so. The old service might not properly shut down anymore and have some resource open (port).

You should see if there is still a red5 executable running using `ps` even after doing `service red5 stop`, or if that fails reboot your machine.

Comment: you could also try `lsof -i :Port_NUmber_Use_By_red` to identify if a process still use the TCP port of the server.

Comment: Actually I fixed it but I don't understand why it worked, so perhaps you could explain why. I just restarted service httpd and service mysqld and after mysqld restarted successfully then red5 restarted...strange.

Comment: I guess reboot the machine is the same.